# Windows form program to accept 3 integer angles as input and checks whether it is a valid triangle by checking the sum against 180 degrees

Tags: vb.net

Write a Windows form program to accept 3 integer angles as input and checks
whether it is a valid triangle by checking the sum against 180 degrees

Comment: It looks like an homework.

Comment: Nothing wrong with asking about a homework assignment but you need to supply the code you have tried as part of you question. Explain where the code errors and what the error is or how the code does not produce the desired results. Take the [tour]

Answer (score 0):

Just create 3 text-boxes and 1 button. Then double-click on the button and write inside this code:

```
dim dSum as integer= CInt(textbox1.text) + CInt(textbox2.text) + CInt(textbox3.text)
if dSum=180 then
    Msgbox ("It's a triangle.")
else
    Msgbox ("It's not a triangle.")
End if
```

You will also need to use the IsNumeric(textbox1.text) to validate if the user inserted a number.